# cannot send pdf attachement using nodemailler

Tags: node.js, nodemailer

I am using nodemailer to send email with pdf attachment, the email is sent successfully, but the pdf attachment is broken when downloaded through the email. Following is my mailOptions:

```
let mailOptions = {
        from: 'writingtest@email.xxx.com', // sender address mailfrom must be same with the user
        to: receiveEmail, // list of receivers,use , to split
        cc:'service@xxx.com', // copy for receivers
        subject: 'writing test from xxx.com', // Subject line
        text: 'Hello world', // plaintext body
        replyTo: 'service@xxx.com', //send reply email address
        attachments: [
            {
                filename: 'test.pdf',
                filePath: '../../files/test.pdf',
                contentType: 'application/pdf',
            }
        ],
    };
```

And the info received from callback is:

```
message sent: 250 Data Ok: queued as freedom ###envid=19950767140
```

Comment: Use an absolute path instead of a relative path for the `filePath` value and see if that fixes the issue.

Comment: absolute path does not fix this issue

Comment: Check whether the file exists before sending:

`const fs = require('fs');` and 
`if (fs.existsSync('../../files/test.pdf')) { `